# How to exclude an Element (via ID) in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS rule like `* {-webkit-transition:all 0.7s ease}`, This applies to all the elements on the page, but I want to exclude an Element from this rule with ID `classic`, how to do this?

Comment: @slhck You rock!! It works. Please add it as an answer so that I can mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The CSS 3 pseudo class for excluding elements is `:not`. To exclude all elements matching `#classic`, but keep the rest, use

```
* :not(#classic) { 
  /* your definitions here */ 
}
```

See the [W3C spec on selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation).

Note that these CSS3 selectors don't work on old browsers, see https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_selectors_not for a support table.